# What's up with this bump?

Tags: support

A particular old [question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/77464/32436) was bumped to the homepage by Community.  Was this done automatically by the software?  Was it a person?  Why was it bumped?  It makes no sense to me.

I read a Meta [outline](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1272/32436) of reasons for bumping, and none of them fit.

I thought that maybe the bump had resulted from an edit, but the question doesn't seem to have been edited.

Comment: The SE Academia Meta answer I linked to wasn't quite as complete as the answer it linked to (which I hadn't noticed until now).  Sometimes SE feels like Calvinball.  I wish there were ONE help page containing all the basic facts.  As things stand one has to hunt around for questions and answers.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano - Okay, I made an adjustment.

Answer (score 4):

Visible on the question right now:

[image: bumped to the homepage by Community 13 hours ago]

The system automatically "bumps" questions that have answers where some are sitting at a score of 0 and none are accepted or score *more* than 0. This gives folks a chance to review the answers and vote on them or post better ones.

In this case, it worked - over the past 13 hours, one of the answers has been upvoted.

#### See also: [How can we make the purpose of Community "bumping" more obvious?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279203/how-can-we-make-the-purpose-of-community-bumping-more-obvious)

Comment: Helpful, but zaq's comment was even more helpful.  (I don't see why the criteria couldn't be put in parentheses in the bump message.)

Comment: Probably could be; debatable how much that matters to most folks. Also, there were concerns about pushing too hard for folks to vote - see the discussion I linked.

Comment: Well, people would not be required to read the fine print....

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @zaq in a comment to an answer that has since been deleted, [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511/287826) explains that to be automatically bumped, a question should

- be open (not locked or closed)
- score no less than zero
- have been inactive for 30 days
- have no accepted answer, no answer scoring more than zero, and at least one non-deleted answer with a score of 0

Automatic bumping cannot occur more frequently than one per hour.